# A risk neutral individual chooses among a pair of gambles.

Tags: statistics, economics

I'm a little confused about the following lecture slide, which is written as follows.

A risk-neutral individual chooses among pairs of gambles

```
{X1,X2} such that Xi = 10 with probability 1.
{Y1, Y2} such that Yi = 0 or 16 with probability ½ each.
{X1, Y1}
```

The expected values of the higher draws are:

E[max{X1,X2}] = 10

E[max{Y1,Y2}] = ¼(0) + ¾(16) = 12

E[max{X1,Y1}] = ½(10) + ½(16) = 13

The expected values of the lower draws are:

E[min{X1,X2}] = 10

E[min{Y1,Y2}] = ¾(0) + ¼(16) = 4

E[min{X1,Y1}] = ½(0) + ½(10) = 5

Specifically, I'm confused as to how to evaluate the expected values of maximum and minimum functions, where the "1/4" and "3/4" weights came from in the E[max/min(Y1,Y2)], and where the "1/2" weights came from in E[max/min(X1,Y1)].  The prof. gave the example of choosing between players with different values for a sports draft, so any clarification as to what's going on here in those terms would also be helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

consider $E[\rm{max\ \{y_1,y_2\}}]$. Prob $y_1$=0 is 1/2, probability $y_2$=0 is 1/2, so the probability they are both 0 is 1/4.  If that case happens, then the max is 0.  Probability that something else happens is 1-1/4=3/4, and something else is either $y_1$ is 16 and $y_2$ is 0, or vice versa, or both $y_1$ and $y_2$ are 16.  In all those cases, the max is 16, so the expected value is 
1/4 (0) + 3/4 (16) = 12.  And the other problems follow a similar logic.